# Calculating pixelwise correlation between two multi-layer rasters in R with the terra package

Tags: r, package, correlation, terra

Is there a function in the R terra package that is equivalent to the raster package's `corLocal()` syntax below

```
corLocal(x, y, method=c("spearman"), test=FALSE)
```

I'd like to calculate the pixelwise correlation between two multi-layer SpatRaster objects. The SpatRasters have the same extent, resolution, and number of layers. I also need to find the p-values for each pixel. I've found `layerCor()`, but it only takes in one SpatRaster as input.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://statnmap.com/2018-01-27-spatial-correlation-between-rasters/

Comment: I does, somewhat. I was looking for a method that relies on the terra package, which I believe would be faster.  Also, I need to extract the p-value along with the correlation itself. Any recommendations? Thanks

Comment: No, there does not appear to be this functionality within Terra. If you want that result, you need to create it another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With terra 1.7-69 you can use `xapp`

This currently is the development version of therra that you can install with:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

Example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.69
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=5)
set.seed(1)
r <- init(r, runif)
s <- init(r, runif)
```

Solution

```
x <- xapp(r, s, fun=cor)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :      lyr.1 
#min value   : -0.9923990 
#max value   :  0.9808943
```

Likewise, you can use `cor.test`, but you have to extract the value(s) you want from what that function returns. For example

```
xtest <- xapp(r, s, fun=\(x, y) cor.test(x, y)$p.value)
```

Unlike `cor`, `cor.test` fails when the input is `NA`. To work around this you can do

```
naproof.cor.test <- function(x, y) {
    if (any(is.na(x)) || any(is.na(y))) return(NA)
    cor.test(x, y)$p.value
}

xtest <- xapp(r, s, naproof.cor.test)
```

And you can get both the correlation coefficient and the p-value in one step like this

```
my.cor <- function(x, y) {
    if (any(is.na(x)) || any(is.na(y))) return(c(NA, NA))
    unlist(cor.test(x, y)[c("estimate", "p.value")])
}

z <- xapp(r, s, my.cor)

z
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : estimate.cor,      p.value 
#min values  :   -0.9923990, 0.0007945862 
#max values  :    0.9808943, 0.9992525680
```

Comment: layerCor() does not seem to work for what I need.  I am looking for a function that returns a Spatraster with the same number of nx and ny points as the input. In other words, the spearman correlation coef. for each pixel

Comment: Because you mentioned `layerCor` I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer.